# Enums defined with array constants

Tags: c, arrays, enums, constants

Is it possible to define enum constants with arrays? Like this:

```
enum myEnum
{
    abc = {12, 34, 56};
    def = {-12, -13, -14};
};
```

Comment: [Ideone says no](http://ideone.com/nBaIDD)

Comment: What would that even mean? If you'll tell us what you're trying to do, we might be able to show you how to do it (using something other than an `enum`).

Comment: I need a way of storing "tuples" of constant information and being able to compare it. In this case I'm using data types and their sizes. Example:

long TYPE_NUMERIC_UNSIGNED_LONG_INT[]      =        {50, 0, 4294967295, 1};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  An enum constant must be an integer type.

From section 6.7.2.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The  expression  that  defines  the  value  of  an  enumeration  constant  **shall  be  an  integer constant expression that has a value
>   representable as an `int`**
>
> *3* **The  identifiers  in  an  enumerator  list  are  declared  as constants  that  have  type `int`** and may   appear   wherever   such  are
>   permitted.  An   enumerator   with `=` defines   its enumeration
>   constant as the value of the constant expression.  If the first
>   enumerator has no `=`, the value of its enumeration constant is 0.  Each
>   subsequent enumerator with no `=` defines  its  enumeration  constant 
>   as  the  value  of  the  constant  expression  obtained  by adding 1
>   to the value of the previous enumeration constant.  (The use of
>   enumerators with `=` may produce enumeration constants with values that
>   duplicate other values in the same enumeration.)  The enumerators of
>   an enumeration are also known as its members.

Answer (score 0):

No.

> An *enumeration* comprises  a  set  of  named  integer  constant  values.

(C2011, 6.2.5/16)

The values of enum constants are of an integer type chosen by the implementation.  They cannot have real type, pointer type, or aggregate type (including array type).  The (optional) value declared for an enumeration constant must be an integer.